# How to cut a vector into groups with equal number of observations in R?

Tags: r, classification, categorical-data, quantile

How to cut a vector into groups containing approximately equal number of observations in R? I also need to know what are the cutting point values, to classify future input.

So basically, I am trying to convert continuous variable into a categorical one with equal number of observations in each category. And I need to know the borders of each category. Please help.

For example:

```
bla <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
blaClass <- cut(bla, 3)
```

Each blaClass contains equal number of observations. But problem is that I have many observations very close to each other or even of the same value, so it's hard to divide them into groups with equal observations.

I tried using quantileCut  but it gives me "breaks are not unique" error.

Comment: Give a dummy example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `dplyr::ntile()` to cut them into quantiles. For example,

```
ntile(bla,3)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

will cut them by `q(1/3)` and `q(2/3)` equally

Comment: How to get the border values?

Comment: @Kaisar if you set n = 3, Q(1/3) and Q(2/3) is border

Comment: So the largest value in a category is the border? No other border value is set by the function?

Answer (score 2):

Using my `santoku` package:

```
library(santoku)
bla <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
chop_equally(bla, 3)
```

Also works with many numbers close together:

```
bla <- rep(1:5, 5) + rnorm(25)/1e8
table(chop_equally(bla, 5, lbl_intervals(raw = TRUE)))

##  [1, 1.8) [1.8, 2.6) [2.6, 3.4) [3.4, 4.2)   [4.2, 5] 
##         5          5          5          5          5
```

Comment: Thanks. It almost worked for everything. However it did not work for one column in my df. It just cut it into one. Why?

Comment: I don't know! Does that column have enough distinct values to chop into n groups?

Answer (score 1):

I think `cut` already works as per your expectation the labels returned are not easy to read. You may turn of the labels with `labels = FALSE`

```
bla <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
blaClass <- cut(bla, 3, labels = FALSE)
blaClass
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```